# Microsoft Word normal.dotm meta data won't save {Company} field

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I am trying to edit the meta data in the Word normal.dotm default template but changes to the {Company} field won't save.   Changes to {Position} are saved but if I delete my name Word just restores this automatically to the template.

Google search on this problem has been fruitless.

(FWIW: I have done this in the default Excel template without any problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a few motnhs ago. 
1. You have to remove office templates folder Called TEMPLATES located here : C:\Users\your user name here\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft.
2. Create a new folder and rename it Templates.
You can follow the step by step in this post : http://kbcomputerrepairs.co.uk/fix-error-normal-dotm-word/
All best
Jym

Comment: If you are the author of the web post you cite, you must say so in your answer.

Comment: To reiterate what Scott said, you need to state your authorship. Your profile picture matches the one on that kbcomputerrepairs article.

Comment: (For the record, both of them are [gravatar.com avatar 134c78bb68222c8e7d6cb7f08d20ef06](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/134c78bb68222c8e7d6cb7f08d20ef06?s=512).)

Comment: Thanks for the link but my problem is different from what you are solving.   I'm not being continuously prompted to save the template, its rather than my changes to the template don't save.
I had previously tried deleting the normal.dotm file and let Work spawn a new one but when I edit that it still doesn't save the changes.  FWIW: My Excel templates in the folder are okay.  I tried deleting the folder and I get the same issue.